# Difference between running a query over a view and its underlying tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

Is there a difference, in performance or otherwise, between running a query over a view or there underlying tables.

There may be aggregations, sorting involved in the query.

Any resources where this subject is dealt is welcome.

Comment: if there are no aggregations involved, then None.

Comment: modified the question, in reply to your comment.

Comment: This might be of some help:

[Link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/575858/difference-between-select-from-table-directly-and-view

Comment: @Seasoned: Just FYI: link definitions of that kind (`[linktext][ref] ... [ref] linkURL`) are not supported in comments. Use this pattern instead: `[linktext](linkURL)`. More info – [Markdown: Comment formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).

Comment: No, I'm poorly stating beware of nested views that at some or more points use aggragations that you might not be ware of...

Answer (score 1):

Ideally a View is just a projection on the underlying tables with optional criteria, generally used to hide certain columns or simplify the complexity involved in joining multiple tables to achieve a particular task etc., and wouldn't have any physical existence in the database. So, a query that is run on the view and a query same as the previous one run on the underlying tables perform in the same way.